# How $f^{-1}(B_{\alpha})$ is open?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

i'm having some confusion in the above theory-

- $f^{-1}(V)$ is open if $f^{-1}(B_{\alpha})$ is open.But how  $f^{-1}(B_{\alpha})$ is open?(this we have to show as said in the second line.)

Comment: $f^{-1}(B_{\alpha})$ does not have to be open, but if it is open (for every $\alpha$) then you can draw the conclusion that $f$ is continuous ("...to prove continuity of $f$ it suffices to show...").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text explains how you can prove continuity of $f$ using the notions of *basis* and *subbasis*.

First, the text says "to prove continuity of $f$, it suffices to show that the inverse image of ever basis element is open" and the next sentence proves that claim. To be precise, that claim is: *if* every $f^{-1}(B_\alpha)$ is open, *then* $f$ is continuous. So there you *assume* that every $f^{-1}(B_\alpha)$ is open and *conclude* that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open.

Second, the text says "to prove continuity of $f$, it will even suffice to show that the inverse image of every subbasis element is open", again followed by a sentence that proves that claim.

Comment: :I still have confusion-We have to prove inverse image of every basis element is open i.e., if $B_{\alpha}$ is a basis element then we've to show $f^{-1}(B_{\alpha})$ is open.And you're assuming $f^{-1}(B_{\alpha})$ to be open?

Comment: The claim is: *if* every $f^{-1}(B_\alpha)$ is open, *then* $f$ is continuous; that is exactly what "to prove continuity of $f$, it suffices to show that the inverse image of ever basis element is open" means.

Answer (score 3):

The point is that you suppose (or prove) that all $f^{-1}[B_\alpha]$ are open and then $f^{-1}[O]$ is open for all open $O$, so $f$ is continuous. If you already know $f$ is continuous, then of course all $f^{-1}[B_\alpha]$ are open, a fortiori (all open sets have open inverse images, so in particular all base elements have).

So to show continuity of $f$ you only have to show (the weaker statement, a priori) that the inverse images under $f$ of the elements of your favourite base or subbase for $Y$ are open in $X$; this can simplify some arguments.